# Yii2. Массив моделей. Как присвоить отдельные атрибуты для обозначения маркеров в Google maps?

Tags: javascript, массивы, yii2, google-maps-api, foreach

Есть модель Firm, которая содержит некоторые атрибуты, вроде type, latitude и longitude.

Рендер в контроллере:

```
public function actionMassage()
{
    return $this->render('massage', [
        'model'=>Firm::findAll(['type'=> '3'])
    ]);
}
```

Нужно присвоить атрибуты latitude и longitude широте и долготе маркеров в Google Maps. Помогите, вроде вопрос не сложный, но что-то не выходит.

Пробую присвоить значения в представлении massage через js:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs('
    var map;
    var marker;
    initMap();

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: {lat:55.25, lng:55.25},
            zoom: 17
        });
        markers = [];
        <?php foreach($model as $key => $value) : ?>

        <?php if($value->latitude && $value->longitude) : ?>

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:{
                lat:<?php echo $value->latitude;?>,
                lng:<?php echo $value->longitude;?>
            },
            map:map}
         );
         markers[<?php echo $key;?>] = marker;
         <?php endif;?>

          <?php endforeach; ?>
     };
');
?>
```

Использую виджет kossmoss/yii2-google-maps-api.

Comment: А что именно не выходит? В $value->latitude есть значения?

Comment: Только ставлю foreach карта перестает показывать, причем app.log никаких ошибок не показывает. $value->latitude ничего  не выводит:(

Comment: Если нет значения, значит и в условие не попадает. Следовательно и маркеры не устанавливаются. Надо смотреть, что в массив моделей попадает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно на стороне php сформировать нужный массив и передать его в js

```
var markers = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($array) ?>')
```

и уже потом пройтись по массиву в js.